# How to find mode across variables/vectors within a data row in R

Tags: r, average

Does anyone know how to find the mode (most frequent across variables for a single case in R?

For example, if I had data on favorite type of fruit (x), asked nine times (x1-x9) for each respondent (id) in a survey. If I wanted to find the modal response for each test subject in the first five times asked, how would I program that in R?

More succinctly, with the example data is below, how do I find the MODE within each case?

```
 id  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  MODE(x1-x5)?  
  1  3   5   6   4   5   5   
  2  7   4   7   4   7   7  
  3  3   4   4   4   3   4  
  4  3   2   2   2   3   2
```

Comment: Your example data and explantation do not match. Where is `id` in your example `data`, are your columns `v1-v5` meant to be labelled `x1-x5`?

Comment: It doesn't appear in your example data, but any reasonable solution will need to know how you intend to handle ties.

Comment: The mode of `c(3,2,2,2,3)` is 7?

Comment: @ML, fixed, thanks. @joran; likely flag and evaluate further (the actual data has more prior information than the example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`modeest`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modeest/index.html) package provides implements a number of estimators of the mode for unimodal univariate data.

This has a function `mfv` to return the most frequent value, or (as `?mfv` states) it is perhaps better to use `mlv(..., method = 'discrete')

```
library(modeest)


## assuming your data is in the data.frame dd

apply(dd[,2:6], 1,mfv)
[1] 5 7 4 2
## or
apply(dd[,2:6], 1,mlv, method = 'discrete')
[[1]]
Mode (most frequent value): 5 
Bickel's modal skewness: -0.2 
Call: mlv.integer(x = newX[, i], method = "discrete") 

[[2]]
Mode (most frequent value): 7 
Bickel's modal skewness: -0.4 
Call: mlv.integer(x = newX[, i], method = "discrete") 

[[3]]
Mode (most frequent value): 4 
Bickel's modal skewness: -0.4 
Call: mlv.integer(x = newX[, i], method = "discrete") 

[[4]]
Mode (most frequent value): 2 
Bickel's modal skewness: 0.4 
Call: mlv.integer(x = newX[, i], method = "discrete")
```

Now, if you have ties for the most frequent, then you need to think about what you want.
both `mfv` and `mlv.integer` will return all the values that tie for the most frequent. (although the print method only shows a single value)

Answer (score 1):

A solution that chooses the lowest value for ties is given by:

```
modeStat = function(vals) {
  return(as.numeric(names(which.max(table(vals)))))
}
modeStat(c(1,3,5,6,4,5))
```

This returns:

```
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `mean` on ties, and returning a vector:

```
> x[-7]
##   x v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
## 1 1  3  4  5  4  5
## 2 2  7  4  7  4  7
## 3 3  3  4  4  4  3
## 4 4  3  2  2  2  3
```

This is not quite the same data as in your question.  The first row has been altered to introduce a tie.

```
require(functional)
apply(x[2:6], 1, Compose(table,
                         function(i) i==max(i),
                         which,
                         names,
                         as.numeric,
                         mean))

## [1] 4.5 7.0 4.0 2.0
```

Replace `mean` with whatever tie-breaking function that you need.